Deneb show debug pane
It is sometimes a hassle resizing in Deneb editor to view the debug pane - here it is missing completely:

and I have to do some resizing of the window with the mouse or make the canvas smaller, which makes it too small to use...

is there any easier way?

I tend to develop in the online editor and then port across.

Two questions - (1) how do you get the data into the online editor and (2) there are some power bi specific signals such as pbiContainerWidth.


I usually develop with a small inline dataset to prototype or create a github gist and read that in. 2. I make adjustments for Deneb right at the end for things that use specific signals

